# SKLabelNode intrinsicContentSize

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sklabelnode

How would you get the `intrinsicContentSize` like for a `UILabel` but for an `SKLabelNode`?

My not-so-educated-guess would be to create a `UILabel` with the same font and just get its' `intrinsicContentSize`... but this seems sloppy.

Comment: In short, you should implement something like that by yourself. See if this helps in some way : http://stackoverflow.com/a/32185228/3402095 SKLabelNode is not the same with UILabel, it is not even similar. It is very basic element actually with limited possibilities (in compare to UILabel).

Comment: Are you looking to find the width of an SKLabelNode of a given string at a given size of a given font?

Comment: @Confused I would say he wants to resize label's width to automatically fit its content.

Comment: @Confused is correct, I am looking for the width of the label

Comment: The size of a label node is determined implicitly by the label node’s fontName, fontSize, and text properties. That is from the docs. To get the label's width, just set text and print label.frame.size.width property.

Comment: Can you expand on how to actually do that (calculate width) @Whirlwind?

Comment: I explained above. just read the frame property (frame.size.width)

Comment: @Whirlwind the frame doesn't necessarily represent the size of the text tho

Comment: I meant label.frame. frame.size property is based on text directly. You should update your question with a minimal example which can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Also there is calculateAccumulatedFrame() method which returns the biggest rectangle that contains the content of the node and all of its descendants.

Comment: @Whirlwind awesome. you're right. you can post that and I'll accept the answer